# Let p be prime number, and suppose $\sigma$ is p-cycle. Probe that for all natural numbers, m, $\sigma^{m}$ is either the identity or a p-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra

My attempt:

Let p be a prime number. Suppose $\sigma$ is  p-cycle, that is $\sigma= (123...p)$. Let $i\in[p]$, then we have that

$\sigma(i)=i+1 (modp)$.

Moreover, if m is a natural number, we have that

$\sigma^{m}(i)=i+m (modp)$.

Notice,

$\sigma^{m}:i (modp) \rightarrow i+m (modp) \rightarrow … \rightarrow i+ (p-1)m (modp) \rightarrow i (modp)$

I elected to split this into cases:

Case I (m|p):

This is pretty straight forward, if m|p then $\sigma^{m}(i)=i$.

Case II (p doesn't divide m):

Then in the mapping defined by:
$\sigma^{m}:i (modp) \rightarrow i+m (modp) \rightarrow … \rightarrow i+ (p-1)m (modp) \rightarrow i (modp)$

Notice, $\sigma^{m}$ will be a p-cycle provided we have that for all distinct x,y$\in ${1,2,...,p-1} we have i+xm$\neq$i+ym(modp)

This is where I am struggling, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $ i+x m = i + y m \mod p$ for $0 \leq x,y < p$, subtract $i$ to get that

$ x m = y m \mod p$ since $p \not |m$ we have that $gcd(p,m)=1$ , so multiply by inverse of $m$ to get that $x = y \mod p$

if $gcd(m,p)>1$ then $ gcd(m,p)=p$ and as you said this is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

Write $\sigma^{m}$ as a product of disjoint cycles. Then the order of $\sigma^{m}$ is the lcm of the order of these cycles. The result follows because the order of $\sigma^{m}$ is $p$ or $1$ — that's the key point.